# Design Leaflet Components to Avoid Memory Leaks

Tags: memory, leaflet

I am using Leaflet in a custom web application to map locations inside a building that update regularly and which are displayed continuously (the web app is always up on a large touchscreen monitor). I'm noticing slow memory leaks in the application that are degrading performance over time, and in comparing snapshots of the application it appears as though the biggest increases in memory utilization are in components of the Leaflet maps.

I've searched around but haven't found any documentation outlining general design principals for Leaflet that will minimize this sort of memory impact over time. Does such a thing exist, or can anybody point me to general design best practices for Leaflet mapping (or maybe even mapping in general) to avoid these times of long-term memory issues?

Thank you!